# How to wait for state update and then render or render updated state in React Js?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am working on a React Js project and using React Redux for log in and user loading. on login page if login is successful user is redirected to Home page. I think user loading takes a while so when first time I redirected to home page user is not yet loaded. but if I visit another page and than return to Home page user is loaded.

**Home.js**

```
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            unread:0,
        }
     }
    componentDidMount() {
        if(this.props.auth.user) (
            console.log('hello) 
      } 
    render() {
    return(
    <div>
        //some code here
    </div>
    )}
    }

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth
});
    
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { })(Home);
```

even after successful login hello is not printing on console when first time after Login I'm redirected to Home page but if I visit another page and than visit Home page **hello** is printed on console.

How can I print this at console at first time?

I used `componentDidUpdate()` in the place of `componentDidMount` this worked but it is printing **hello** on console continuously many times. But I want it only once. how is that possible?

help please!

Comment: add the redux code that updates `state.auth` and redirects

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by just adding a extra boolean parameter in this.state

```
    class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            unread:0,
            userCheckedOnce: false

        }
     }
    componentDidMount() {
        if(this.props.auth.user && !this.state.userCheckedOnce) {
            console.log('hello)
            this.setState({unread: 0,userCheckedOnce: true}) 
      } 
    render() {
    return(
    <div>
        //some code here
    </div>
    )}
    }

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth
});
    
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { })(Home);
```